# Unable to navigate sidebar content when I use iframes for each one of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, dynamic

So I have my page with a top nav bar, a side bar and content at right. Now I have my pages designed, but i felt it to be repetitive, so I was trying to work out with iframes in the right side(the one that changes when any link in the sidebar is changed). I hope you get the idea.

Now, the issue is that I am able to navigate to second iframe tag from 1st but not from second to first iframe.

Here's the code.
HTML:

```
        <div class="container-fluid side-content">

          <iframe src="carsx-iframe.html" id="car-frame" height="100%" width="100%" style="outline: none; border:none; "></iframe>

          <iframe src="edit-profile-iframe.html" id="edit-prof" height="1050px" width="100%" style="outline: none; border-style: none;"></iframe>

        </div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit-prof-click").click(function() {
    $("#edit-prof").show();
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cars").click(function() {
    $("#car-frame").show();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#edit-prof{
  display: none;
}

#car-frame{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the second div to show the first one and you arent doing that when trying to show the first.

Try adding something like

```
$("#car-frame").hide();
```

Before showing the first iframe.